# Binding with optional struct

Tags: binding, viewmodel, option-type

I get the error "Value of optional type 'Photo?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'name' of wrapped base type 'Photo'" when I try to send a optional struct on a binding of a TextField.

The content view code example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()
    
    private var photos = [
        Photo(id: UUID(), name: "Exclamation", data: (UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))!),
        Photo(id: UUID(), name: "Circle", data: (UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))!)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DetailView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.selectedPhoto = photos[0]
        }
    }
}
```

The view model code example:

```
import Foundation

@MainActor
final class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var photos = [Photo]()
    @Published var selectedPhoto: Photo?
}
```

The detail view code example (that uses the content view's view model):

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Photo name here...", text: $viewModel.selectedPhoto.name)
    }
}
```

Note that for some reasons I need the selectedPhoto property be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom `@Binding`, so you can handle the process between getting data and set the updated here is an example:

- If what you want is to select the photo in a `List` or `Foreach` you can bind directly to the array.

  import SwiftUI

  ```
   struct Photo {
       let id: UUID
       var name: String
       let data: Data
   }

   @MainActor
   final class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var photos = [Photo]()
       @Published var selectedPhoto: Photo?
   }

   struct optionalBinding: View {

       @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()

       private var photos = [
           Photo(id: UUID(), name: "Exclamation", data: (UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))!),
           Photo(id: UUID(), name: "Circle", data: (UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))!)
       ]

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               DetailView2(viewModel: viewModel)

               Button("Select Photo") {
                   viewModel.selectedPhoto = photos[0]
               }
           }
       }
   }

   struct DetailView2: View {
       @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewViewModel

       var body: some View {
           Text(viewModel.selectedPhoto?.name ?? "No photo selected")
           TextField("Photo name here...", text: optionalBinding())
       }

       func optionalBinding() -> Binding<String> {
           return Binding<String>(
               get: {
                   guard let photo = viewModel.selectedPhoto else {
                       return ""
                   }
                   return photo.name
               },
               set: {
                   guard let _ = viewModel.selectedPhoto else {
                       return
                   }
                   viewModel.selectedPhoto?.name = $0
                   //Todo: also update the array
               }
           )
       }
   }
  ```

[image]